# HERE API - Store POI ID from API Call

Tags: here-api

I'm looking to HERE API, I will want to get places details and autocomplete. I'm aware that isn't allowed to store API call response results for more than 30 days, but could we store at least POI Id?

I want to be allowed to store at least place identifier, as this will be on scope of trips planning app, and if a user selects a place, I want to be able to get the details from it when the user opens the trip.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ask these use case-based questions directly on their [slack](https://heredev.slack.com/) channel or by opening a support ticket